# Could not initiate tui-image-editor on Localhost

Tags: javascript, toast-ui-image-editor

I am trying to initialize, tui-image-editor on my local host. I have downloaded this famous image editor from https://github.com/nhn/tui.image-editor

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TUI Image Editor</title>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.7.0/fabric.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui.code-snippet/v1.5.0/tui-code-snippet.min.js"></script>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/imageEditor/dist/tui-image-editor.css">
<script src="http://localhost/imageEditor/dist/tui-image-editor.js"></script>
<script>

var ImageEditor = require('tui-image-editor');

var instance = new ImageEditor(document.querySelector('#tui-image-editor'), {
     includeUI: {
         loadImage: {
             path: 'jp.jpg',
             name: 'SampleImage'
         },

         theme: blackTheme, // or whiteTheme
         initMenu: 'filter',
         menuBarPosition: 'bottom'
     },
    cssMaxWidth: 700,
    cssMaxHeight: 500,
    selectionStyle: {
        cornerSize: 20,
        rotatingPointOffset: 70
    }
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="tui-image-editor" style="height: 200px">
    <canvas></canvas>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

In result, I am getting blank page, No error no warning

I am not getting way out of this situation, could you please identify where I am doing bad ?

Comment: are you trying to run this standalone or as a node.js project?

Comment: Using standalone, as you see in this code, all this what I had

Comment: When i run this standalone and look at the console, there are errors, however you say there are none. To use `require()` you need to create a node.js project and download the package `tui-image-editor` from the node package manager EDIT: Or use requireJS

Comment: I checked now the Console, its giving error, require is not defined, How can i use requireJS

Comment: In this tutorial, they did not mentioned anything else like Require or Node https://github.com/nhn/tui.image-editor/blob/master/docs/Basic-Tutorial.md

Comment: After I use, require.js, It start giving me these errors, Module name "tui-image-editor" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Comment: I haven't used requireJS, only Node.js, so i'm not sure what that error could mean. On another note, the tutorial you linked does not mention using a `require()` statement, only importing scripts via HTML, which most probably will import `tui.component.ImageEditor`